# Port a Tomcat Application to App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a tomcat/mysql website that I would like to move over to Google app engine does anyone know of a good tutorial outlining this?  Or can anyone make some suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Yes it did very much.  Thanks sorry for the late response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you use standard servlet and JSPs you will be fine.

The limitations for Google App Engine are documented here : http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html

Sessions are kind of expensive (read slow) so avoid state on the server as much as possible.

The backing store is also quite different than standard SQL if you use any db calls in your app.